# Verify path traversal vulnerability in web server

Tags: security, curl, directory-traversal

I want to verify that my web application does not have a path traversal vulnerability.

I'm trying to use `curl` for that, like this:

```
$ curl -v http://www.example.com/directory/../
```

I would like the HTTP request to be explicitly made to the `/directory/../` URL, to test that a specific nginx rule involving proxy is not vulnerable to path traversal. I.e., I would like this HTTP request to be sent:

```
> GET /directory/../ HTTP/1.1
```

But `curl` is rewriting the request as to the `/` URL, as can be seen in the output:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.example.com/
(...)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
```

Is it possible to use `curl` for this test, forcing it to pass the exact URL in the request? If not, what would be an appropriate way?

Comment: Which version of `curl` are you using?  I can't seem to replicate this behavior, at least not when I `curl` a localhost URL.

Answer (score 38):

The curl flag you are looking for is `curl --path-as-is` .

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a way to do it via `curl`, but you could always use `telnet`.  Try this command:

`telnet www.example.com 80`

You'll see:

`Trying xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx...
Connected to www.example.com.
Escape character is '^]'.`

You now have an open connection to www.example.com.  Now just type in your command to fetch the page:

`GET /directory/../ HTTP/1.1`

And you should see your result. e.g.

`HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [intercepting proxy](http://thewasps.blogspot.co.uk/2008/02/tools.html) to capture a request to your application and repeat the request with parameters changed, such as the raw URL that is requested from the application.

The free version of [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) will allow this using the Repeater.

However, there are alternatives that should also allow this such as [Zap](https://code.google.com/p/zaproxy/), [WebScarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project) and [Fiddler2](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).